# Determine if an HTML element's content overflows

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can I use JavaScript to check (irrespective of scrollbars) if an HTML element has overflowed its content? For example, a long div with small, fixed size, the overflow property set to visible, and no scrollbars on the element.

Comment: I don't think this answer is perfect. Sometimes the scrollWidth/clientWidth/offsetWidth are the same even though the text is overflow. This works well in Chrome, but not in IE and Firefox. At last, I tried this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738117/html-text-overflow-ellipsis-detection It's perfect and works well anywhere. So I choose this, maybe you can try, you won't disappoint.

Answer (score 277, accepted):

Normally, you can compare the `client[Height|Width]` with `scroll[Height|Width]` in order to detect this... but the values will be the same when overflow is visible. So, a detection routine must account for this:

```
// Determines if the passed element is overflowing its bounds,
// either vertically or horizontally.
// Will temporarily modify the "overflow" style to detect this
// if necessary.
function checkOverflow(el)
{
   var curOverflow = el.style.overflow;

   if ( !curOverflow || curOverflow === "visible" )
      el.style.overflow = "hidden";

   var isOverflowing = el.clientWidth < el.scrollWidth 
      || el.clientHeight < el.scrollHeight;

   el.style.overflow = curOverflow;

   return isOverflowing;
}
```

Tested in FF3, FF40.0.2, IE6, Chrome 0.2.149.30.

Comment: thank you Shog9... the detection routine is, i think, what i needed, because i play with overflow (hidden/visible)

Comment: I have a similar question over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023787/how-to-determine-if-hidden-overflow-text-is-at-top-or-bottom-of-element where I am trying to figure out what parts of the containing element have hidden overflow.

Comment: I wonder whether this will give a short flicker as the style is briefly changed?

Comment: +1. This works on modern browsers (including at least Chrome 40 and other current version browsers from the time of this writing).

Comment: Does not work in MS Edge. Sometimes content is not overflowing but `clientWidth` and `scrollWidth` differs by 1px.

Comment: clientWidth and scrollWidth shows zero for elements loaded using jquery div.load

$('#div1').load(myUrl,function(){
 var el = $('myElement'); 
 checkOverflow(el)
});

Comment: Put together a test case & ask a new question about that, @Gk_999

Comment: Will this work for multiple line ellipsis that is achieved via the -webkit-line-clamp? https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/

Comment: @Shog9 - Sorry I meant to say that it is not working for the multiple line ellipsis that is achieved via the -webkit-line-clamp. I am simply doing a comparison of offsetWidth and clientWidth, and the values are the same for both regardless of whether the ellipsis is displayed. Wondering if you or someone else has made this work for multiple line ellipsis.

Comment: I see, @AshD. You're *probably* going to have to dynamically drop and re-add the `-webkit-line-clamp` style, just as I do for the `overflow` style in this example. Might get a bit messy if there's no sensible default; post a new question if you run into trouble.

Comment: Works, but without adding overflow:hidden

Answer (score 25):

Try comparing `element.scrollHeight` / `element.scrollWidth` to `element.offsetHeight` / `element.offsetWidth` :

```js
if (element.scrollHeight > element.offsetHeight) {
  console.log('element overflows')
}
```

See MDN docs :

- [offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth)
- [offsetHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight)
- [scrollWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollWidth)
- [scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight)

Comment: it looks working in Chrome and Safari

Answer (score 6):

Another way is compare the element width with its parent's width:

```js
function checkOverflow(elem) {
    const elemWidth = elem.getBoundingClientRect().width
    const parentWidth = elem.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect().width

    return elemWidth > parentWidth
}
```

Comment: the child element is usually contained or shrinks to fit the parent element. How do you get around this?

Comment: @CWSites if you're talking about images, try to use `object-fit: cover;`

Comment: I'm not asking about images, just a DOM element such as a `div` or `span`

Comment: Probably is because it was the `width` or `max-width` set to `100%` or `-webkit-fill-available`

Answer (score 5):

I didn't like any of these, so I wrote this one.  Works great!

```js
function isOverflowY(element) {
  return element.scrollHeight != Math.max(element.offsetHeight, element.clientHeight)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you could do:

```
if ( $(".inner-element").prop('scrollHeight') > $(".inner-element").height() ) {

    console.log("element is overflowing");

} else {

    console.log("element is not overflowing");

}
```

Change to `.prop('scrollWidth')` and `.width()` if needed.