# Truncating html text appropriately into a fixed size area

Tags: javascript, html, css

In a generated html page, we have a fixed size area (lets say 200 x 300) in which we need to fit in as much text as possible (like a regular paragraph of text), and if it doesn't fit, remove an appropriate number of characters and append "..." to the end.

The text is NOT in a fixed sized font, and although we are using one specific font for this text, a "generic" solution would obviously be preferred.

This looked interesting, but I'm thinking it would be very slow with this function being called for several items on a page - http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/93847-neatly-truncating-text-fit-physical-dimension

The solution can use an intermix of html, css, js, and php as needed.

Suggestions on approaches are more than welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Set the element dimensions via CSS and its overflow to "hidden".

Then, find out with this function, if the element's content is overflowing ([via](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143815/how-to-determine-from-javascript-if-an-html-element-has-overflowing-content)):

```
// Determines if the passed element is overflowing its bounds,
// either vertically or horizontally.
// Will temporarily modify the "overflow" style to detect this
// if necessary.
function checkOverflow(el)
{
   var curOverflow = el.style.overflow;
   if ( !curOverflow || curOverflow === "visible" )
      el.style.overflow = "hidden";

   var isOverflowing = el.clientWidth < el.scrollWidth 
      || el.clientHeight < el.scrollHeight;

   el.style.overflow = curOverflow;

   return isOverflowing;
}
```

Now, in a loop remove text and check until it is not overflowing anymore. Append an ellipsis character (`String.fromCharCode(8230)`) to the end, but only if it was overflowing.

To avoid any flickering effects during that operation, you can try working on a hidden copy of the element, but I'm not sure if the browsers do the necessary layout calculations on an element that's not visible. (Can anyone clarify that?)

Comment: Wait a second... that's a SO question! Better to link to the actual question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143815

Comment: @Yi: Thanks for the cross link. :-)

Comment: :( :( :( - isnt there an 'elegant' way of doing this ...? Dont mind doing some maths to figure out what would work...

Comment: Isnt there some html/css table setting that sets the width to be fixed and it does not move at all (cutting off the remaining text)?

Comment: @tzmatt For your first question: It's not possible to predict the height of the elements until it is rendered on the page by the browser itself. For the second one, you're looking at `overflow: hidden`, although the phrasing in your question precludes that option.

Comment: @tzmatt: If you set the width and/or height in CSS, it *will* "not move at all". Regarding "elegant"… Layout is hard, especially in HTML. Let the browser do that, and deal with what is reality afterwards. Internet Explorer supports `overflow: ellipsis;` which pretty much is exactly what you want, and a pretty smart addition to the standard if you ask me, but the setting is not cross-browser compatible unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that the solution you found is the best. It is, for instance, used for this [jQuery plugin](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/) which autoresizes textareas as you enter text into it. I took the concept and rewrote it with jQuery for this simple test here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZDr5K/

```
var para = $('#para');
var height = 200;

while(para.height() >= height){
    var text = para.text();

    para.text(text.substring(0, text.length - 4) + '...');
}
```

Possible improvements would include right trimming and removing the period if the last character is a full stop. Removing word by word would also be more readable/slightly faster.

As for the function running multiple times, that would be unavoidable. The only thing you can really do with CSS here is to use `:after` to append the ellipses, but even that should be avoided for cross-compatibility problems.