# Javascript: How to identify if a "div" is overflowed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `div` with `overflow: auto` (a vertical scroll bar appears if the `div` contains a lot info).

How could I identify at some point if the vertical scroll bar appears or not ?

Comment: Sorry, can you maybe expand on that a bit. Do you  mean use javascript to detect when the scroll bar appears and if so trigger an event?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine from Javascript if an html element has overflowing content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143815/how-to-determine-from-javascript-if-an-html-element-has-overflowing-content)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/157924-detect-if-scrollbars-visible-inside-div:

```
if (document.getElementById('divID').scrollHeight > document.getElementById('divID').clientHeight)
{
//a vertical scroll bar is present
}
else
{
//a vertical scroll bar is NOT present
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been answered **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143815/how-to-determine-from-javascript-if-an-html-element-has-overflowing-content)**