# Check if div is actually overflowing and/or has scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow

We have a page with a `<DIV style="overflow:auto; height:400px;>`...`</DIV>` section populated with info from a database. Sometimes it contains more text than is visible (hence `overflow:auto`) and we get a vertical scrollbar.

We would like to change the bottom-border of the `<DIV>` section to **red color IF the text overflows** - and as such NOT when we don't have a vertical scrollbar (= the red bottom-border indicates there is more data, because people don't always see pay attention to the scrollbar).

How can this be accomplished?

Setting "`border-bottom:1px solid red;`" will make the bottom-border red all the time, also when the amount of text doesn't dictate overflow/scrollbars, so that alone won't cut it.

---

EDIT: You guys are fast, thanks! I will look into the suggestions - thanks again!

Comment: I'm not sure how useful it will be - the presence of the scrollbar is a universal indicator of more content - if the users don't pay attention to *it*, how likely are they to acknowledge a "convention" that exists on one page of a single application?

Comment: i think the way is checking the div content width... ex: var x = $(div).html(); if(x.width() > $(div).width()){ /* execute animate border */ }

Comment: Very similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138772/how-to-detect-overflow-in-div-element

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Scrolls don't render on IOS.

Comment: I think a call to action that there is more content, that expands the section to show the extra content is a better solution. What does a red border mean to people?

Answer (score 4):

```
if (myDiv[0].scrollHeight > myDiv.innerHeight()){
     //this has overflowing contetent!
}
else{
   //remove border, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

css

```
.attention{border-bottom:1px solid red;}
```

js

```
$.document(ready(function(){
  var div = ('div#YOUR_OVERFLOW_DIV');

  if ( (div).height()>400){
     $(div).addClass('attention');
  }


});
```