# Is there a way to listen to a div overflow event?

Tags: javascript, dom, overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect overflow in div element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138772/how-to-detect-overflow-in-div-element)

Is there a cross-browser way to listen to div overflow?

Something like: `$('#myDiv').bind("divOverflow", function(){alert('div overflowed!')})`

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by comparing scrollHeight with clientHeight.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetContainerSize ()
{
    var container = document.getElementById ("tempDiv");
    var message = "The width of the contents with padding: " + container.scrollWidth + "px.\n";
    message += "The height of the contents with padding: " + container.scrollHeight + "px.\n";

    alert (message);
}
</script>
```

For more info: [How to detect overflow in div element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138772/how-to-detect-overflow-in-div-element)

Answer (score 0):

You could set an interval and check if the element's `scrollHeight > offsetHeight`. There is no built-in event for this.