# Pad header the width of the scrollbar using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a header div above a scrolling div and I'd like to pad the header on the right the same width as the scrollbar. I know I can use JavaScript to calculate the scrollbar width, but I was wondering if there's a pure CSS method to do this?

**Edit**

To complicate this more, if there are few results that come back so the scrolling div doesn't produce a scrollbar, then I'd want the header to not be padded as well. I'm not sure if that's possible using only CSS, but thought it's worth asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about "forcing" an `overflow-y:scroll` then making it non-visible?

```
#myDiv{
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
#myDiv::-webkit-scrollbar {
  opacity:0;
}
```

A [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/rwWGGB)

I have to mention that I just had this idea...
You'll have to test it for browser compatibility.

Comment: If it works, that would take care of the first part of my question, but then I still need a way for it to be applied conditionally if the div below has a scrollbar or not.

Comment: That absolutely need JS to be determined.

Comment: But to make a short answer... I would use [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7139047/2159528) to determine if there is an overflow in the scrollable `div`... **And** my idea as a class to add/remove to the non-scrollable one. ;) Good luck|

Comment: For IE, I couldn't find a way to set the opacity, but I was able to set the color to match the background. After doing that, this worked well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all major browsers have the same width, no calculation necessary:

http://www.textfixer.com/tutorials/browser-scrollbar-width.php

Would it be acceptable to just put that in the CSS?

Comment: Please see my edit. It might be, but I'd still have to detect if there was a scrollbar or not so I know whether to pad the header or not.

Comment: Also, with possibly different zooming behavior or accessibility needs, I'm not sure I want to chance it.