# iOS: Split large HTML content into multiple horizontal paginated views

Tags: html, ios, swift, uiwebview

I am given a large HTML content (let's say a huge blog post). The objective is to render this HTML content into multiple pages (paginated application). For clarity, instead of vertical scrolling in a `UIWebView`, the content is split like a book (i.e. you turn the pages to move to the rest of the content, instead of scrolling down in a typical `UIWebView`).

I looked up on SO for similar posts. Unfortunately, these posts haven't been so useful in my case. For reference, here are the similar SO posts:

1. [Split html string into multiple pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006766/split-html-string-into-multiple-pages)
2. [How to divide the webview content in multiple pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29718829/how-to-divide-the-webview-content-in-multiple-pages)
3. [Present html content as dynamic "pages"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131303/present-html-content-as-dynamic-pages)
4. External reference: https://recalll.co/app/?q=android%20webview%20-%20Split%20html%20string%20into%20multiple%20pages

How can I achieve page-based (non-vertical scrolling) application given the HTML content?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but just in case:)

Your question has a very simple solution. Each object of `UIWebView` has a field called `scrollView` which is an object of `UIScrollView` class. UIScrollView support pagination by setting these values:

```
webView.scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true // enable pagination
webView.paginationMode = .leftToRight // set horizontal mode
webView.paginationBreakingMode = .page // pages or columns (latter need css support though)
```

Then you can fill your `webView` with data calling `loadHTMLString`:

```
guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "NameOfYourFile", ofType: "html") else {
    return
}
guard let data = FileManager.default.contents (atPath: path) else {
    return
}
guard let contentString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
    return
}
let webView = UIWebView(frame: view.frame)
webView.loadHTMLString(contentString, baseURL: nil)    
view.addSubview(webView)
```

That's all you need to do here. For the record, I put the code lines above inside `viewDidLoad` method in my test project.