# Apply a particular style to an element only if that element is overflowing

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to apply a particular style to an element conditionally on it overflowing?

E.g. if I have say:

```
<div>
    This text is very long, no really it is extremely long; it just goes on and on and on and on. You might say it's a bit like the Duracell(R) bunny, but without the batteries, and the floppy ears.
</div>
```

and

```
div {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

// TODO: is there any way to only apply this rule if the text is overflowing?
div {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Is there any way using pure CSS to have the background-color: red rule apply only if the text is overflowing?

Note: I can see a way of doing this using javascript; I just want to know if there is a pure CSS way to do it.

Comment: CSS 2.1/3 has no selector for an overflow condition.  Even a JavaScript solution would be interesting.  You might expand your question to invite a jQuery/JavaScript solution.

Comment: Not possible in pure CSS. Here is JS solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143815/how-to-determine-using-javascript-if-html-element-has-overflowing-content