# CSS Media Detect Overflow

Tags: html, css

I'd like to detect whether the web page is flowing over the Y axis, aka it is higher than the display and if so, affect styles.

I am looking for a purely CSS solution, or as close to that as possible.

How would I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine if an HTML element's content overflows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143815/determine-if-an-html-elements-content-overflows)

Comment: @FaustoNA, I was looking for a purely CSS solution, such as a media query though. As far as I know, this hasn't been asked before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am looking for a purely CSS solution [...] such as a `@media query`

In standards-based (real-world) web development, `@element queries` (as opposed to `@media queries`) are still hypothetical.

If they weren't, your CSS-only solution could be something like:

```
@element body and (min-height: 101vh) {

[... STYLES HERE...]

}
```

In the meantime, read:

[**Element Queries for CSS**](http://codepen.io/tomhodgins/post/element-queries-for-css) by Tommy Hodgins (September 30, 2015)

and have a look at

[**eqCSS**](https://github.com/eqcss/eqcss) on Github

---

***Further Reading:***

- **[Thoughts on Media Queries for Elements](http://www.jonathantneal.com/blog/thoughts-on-media-queries-for-elements/)** by Jonathan T Neal (Feb 7, 2013)
- **[Media Queries are a Hack](http://ianstormtaylor.com/media-queries-are-a-hack/)** by Ian Storm Taylor (Apr 1, 2013)
- **[Media Queries Are Not The Answer: Element Query Polyfill](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/06/media-queries-are-not-the-answer-element-query-polyfill/)** by Tyson Matanich (June 25, 2013)
- **[Beyond Media Queries — It’s Time to Get Elemental](http://www.sitepoint.com/beyond-media-queries-time-get-elemental/)** by Richa Jain (March 26, 2015)
- **[Container Queries: Once More Unto the Breach](http://alistapart.com/article/container-queries-once-more-unto-the-breach)** by Mat Marquis (June 30, 2015)

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Years have passed since this was asked and answered.  We now have `CSS container queries`, which would be the equivalent of the 'element queries' mentioned in the original answer.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries

There are some great YouTube videos on this!