# Removing tooltip event from an element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an element with a text that shows a tooltip when the text is truncated. I want to remove the tooltip when the element's text is no longer truncated. The problem is I can't get to the event of the tooltip. I add the tooltip by setting the attribute to the element on truncation. However, removing the attribute doesn't remove the event and the tooltip still shows up. I am using [Angular bootstrap tooltip](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip).
I searched the internet and removeEventListener() didn't help because I don't have the tooltip event handler. The only workaround I was able to use and worked is triggering the event mouseleave on the element which hid the tooltip, not removed it. I think this is not a good way of doing it, I need to remove that event.
By the way, I am using angular and javascript only, no jQuery.

Any ideas how to do this?

Edit:
My element is like this:

```
<span>Here goes the text</span>
```

and after adding the tooltip the element looks like this

```
<span uib-tooltip="Here goes the text" tooltip-append-to-body="true" tooltip-placement="bottom">Here goes the text</span>
```

Comment: Post your HTML code.

Comment: I edited the question and added the html code

Answer (score 0):

You should provide `tooltip-enable` expression in attributes which will return if text is truncated or not. This can be easily determined like so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/143889/2337927. Keep in mind though that you can't use DOM elements directly in angular expressions due to [security issues](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/isecdom). What you want to do is for example register `isTextOverflowing` function on controller and call it from the expression: `tooltip-enable="vm.isTextOverflowing()"`

---

## Edit

If you are positive that what you want is to remove event listener completely then I'm afraid that will involve writing a [decorator](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/decorators) but in really messy (or even hacky) way **but** if what you're up to is simply closing the tooltip when text becomes fully visible it's easy to accomplish using combination of `tooltip-enable` and `tooltip-is-open` such as [shown in this plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/N6wxJMu5Xa7yD6sdZYse?p=preview).

Comment: I am giving you a useful answer because your answer is good but it is not what I am looking for. I need to remove the event attached to that element if that's possible.

Comment: By removing the event you mean removing event listener or closing the tooltip when text becomes fully visible (not truncated)?