# How to create new page element for exceed content?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to create a number of `<page></page>` class `a4` depending on at the amount of content inside it. If the content exceed the height of `<page></page>`, I would like to create a new `<page></page>` for content that exceed from previous page.

```js
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('a4')[0];

var editorHeight = element.offsetHeight;

var pages = element.childElementCount * 1123;

var pageNumber = element.getElementsByClassName('a4').length + 1;

if (editorHeight < pages) {

  var newPage = document.createElement('page');
  newPage.setAttribute('size', 'A4');
  newPage.setAttribute('class', 'a4');
  newPage.dataset.pages = pageNumber;
  element.appendChild(newPage);


}
```

```css
body {
  background: rgb(204, 204, 204);
}

page {
  background: white;
  display: block;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

page[size="A4"] {
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
  padding: 20px;
}

@media print {
  body,
  page {
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<page size="A4">
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
  one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
  et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
  1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English
  versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor
  at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from
  sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem
  ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced
  in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over
  2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered
  the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance.
  The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum
  et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical
  Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites
  of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the
  theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested.
  Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply
  random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from
  a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero,
  written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since
  the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
  one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
  et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
  1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English
  versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor
  at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from
  sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem
  ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced
  in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over
  2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered
  the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance.
  The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum
  et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical
  Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites
  of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the
  theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested.
  Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply
  random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from
  a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero,
  written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since
  the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
  one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
  et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
  1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English
  versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor
  at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from
  sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem
  ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced
  in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over
  2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered
  the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance.
  The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum
  et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
</page>
```

From above code, as I inspected the new `<page class='a4'></page>` was created but I could not get the exceed content and put them in a new created `page`.

How can I do to get new page filled with exceed content from previous page?

Comment: Were do you want to split? At a whole sentence or word or at the exact overflowing character?

Comment: [This similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45018268/detect-word-the-causes-overflow/45018839#45018839) might be helpful

Comment: @JonasW. I would like to split at the exact overflowing character, this would create two or more pages to house the exceed content. Thanks.

Comment: @JonasW. from answer in link above is say how to get just only once overflow word while hide the rest of overflow, it is not exactly apply to my case. Thanks.

Comment: Aside: `Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.` Which people actually believe it's random text? I always knew it came from a classic Roman script.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, it’s random dummy text which I used to represent my real case thanks.

Comment: What is the source of your html i.e is it something like __tinymce__ type text editor that generates html from non-programmer text input?

Comment: @MunimMunna, I used summernote editor https://summernote.org/ for this purpose, Thanks.

Comment: @HouyNarun check my answer, if this is what you looking for.

Comment: @MunimMunna, sorry for late feedback. Yes very much thanks it's working as fine, yet there was one time, script keep loading none stop, until I close browser and open again, thereafter, it's woking fine. Anyway, could you please how I can add page number to bottom of each ex, page 1 of 3. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please post a list of all HTML-tags which could occur in the `page`-element?

Comment: @tavkomann, sure here is a list of html tags often occured in page element `p, span, u, b, i, center, ul, ol, li, table, thead, tbody, tfoot, tr, td, th, br, div, img, font,form,input`, and might have `style`, `class` and `id`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [Summer Note](https://summernote.org/) or similar type of html editor, we can eliminate the idea of having text nodes in your html, because these editors normally wrap everything within `<p>` tags. For example if you write the following

```
This is First Line
This is Second Line
This is Third Line
```

The editor will generate HTML like this.

```
<p>This is First Line</p>
<p>This is Second Line</p>
<p>This is Third Line</p>
```

The generated HTML can also have Tables, Lists and may be Images,

```
<h2>A Title</h2>
<p>A 2-3 line paragraph</p>
<hr><!-- just to prettify -->
<table>...</table>
<ul><li>An Un-ordered List</li></ul>
<ol><li>An Un-ordered List</li></ol>
<p><img src="#" alt="An Image"></p>
```

There is **no way** we can split them into pages without any **trade-offs**. So if we are **okay** with some trade-offs we can get this done. One good thing about these HTML Editors is that they tend to generate mostly [Block level Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) as direct child to the page. So by calculating the position and height of each Block element child we can check if the child fits into the page with simple algorihtm or move it to the next page if it doesn't.

```js
function arrangePage($pageElement, index) {
  if (!index) index = 1;
  var pageHeight = $pageElement.height();
  var children = $pageElement.children();
  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    var child = children.eq(i);
    if(i == 0 && child.height() > pageHeight) continue; /* Infinite loop fix :: explained in answer*/
    var bottom = child.height() + child[0].offsetTop;
    if (bottom < pageHeight) continue;
    var newPage = $('<page size="A4">').appendTo('body').append(children.splice(i));
    arrangePage(newPage, index + 1);
  }
  $('<span>').addClass('page-number').html('Page ' + index).appendTo($pageElement); /* Inerts Page Index*/
}
$(function() {
  arrangePage($("page"));
});
```

```css
body {
  background: rgb(204, 204, 204);
}

page {
  position: relative; /* This is mandatory */
  background: white;
  display: block;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

page[size="A4"] {
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media print {
  body,
  page {
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
  }
}
.page-number {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    left: 8px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #9e4200de;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<page size="A4"><p><span style="color: inherit; font-family: inherit; font-size: 14px;"></span></p><h2 class="entry-title fusion-post-title" data-fontsize="18" data-lineheight="27" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 28px; font-size: 18px; font-family: museo-slab-300, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 27px; padding-bottom: 0px;">Blog Image Post</h2><h2><div class="post-content" style=""><p style="text-align: center; color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><img src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Universal-Placeholder-Text-Lorem-Ipsum-Generator-getlorem.jpg" style="width: 425px;"><span style="color: rgb(107, 113, 122);"><br></span></p><p style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><span style="color: rgb(107, 113, 122);">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(107, 113, 122);">one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source.</span></p><h3 style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><ul style="box-sizing: inherit; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 15px;"><li style="box-sizing: inherit;">Item</li><li style="box-sizing: inherit;">Item</li><li style="box-sizing: inherit;">Item</li><li style="box-sizing: inherit;">Item</li></ul></h3><h3 style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; margin-bottom: 20px;">Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of&nbsp; "de Finibus Bonorum&nbsp;<span style="color: rgb(107, 113, 122);">et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance.</span><br></h3><ol style="box-sizing: inherit; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 15px;"><li style="box-sizing: inherit;">First item</li><li style="box-sizing: inherit;">Second item</li><li style="box-sizing: inherit;">Third item</li><li style="box-sizing: inherit;">Fourth item</li></ol><p style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><span style="color: rgb(107, 113, 122);">The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section</span><span style="color: rgb(107, 113, 122);">&nbsp; 1.10.32.&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(107, 113, 122);">The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(107, 113, 122);">versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</span></p><table id="example" class="ui celled table dataTable" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="grid" aria-describedby="example_info" style="box-sizing: inherit; border-collapse: separate; width: 865px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); margin: 0px; border: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.15); box-shadow: none; border-radius: 0.285714rem; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); font-size: 14px; font-family: Lato, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><thead style="box-sizing: inherit; box-shadow: none;"><tr role="row" style="box-sizing: inherit;"><th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Name: activate to sort column descending" style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.928571em 20px 0.928571em 0.785714em; text-align: inherit; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; cursor: auto; background: rgb(249, 250, 251); vertical-align: inherit; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); border-left: none; position: relative; border-radius: 0.285714rem 0px 0px; width: 137px;">Name</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Position: activate to sort column ascending" style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.928571em 20px 0.928571em 0.785714em; text-align: inherit; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; cursor: auto; background: rgb(249, 250, 251); vertical-align: inherit; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); position: relative; width: 224px;">Position</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Office: activate to sort column ascending" style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.928571em 20px 0.928571em 0.785714em; text-align: inherit; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; cursor: auto; background: rgb(249, 250, 251); vertical-align: inherit; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); position: relative; width: 104px;">Office</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Age: activate to sort column ascending" style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.928571em 20px 0.928571em 0.785714em; text-align: inherit; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; cursor: auto; background: rgb(249, 250, 251); vertical-align: inherit; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); position: relative; width: 39px;">Age</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Start date: activate to sort column ascending" style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.928571em 20px 0.928571em 0.785714em; text-align: inherit; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; cursor: auto; background: rgb(249, 250, 251); vertical-align: inherit; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); position: relative; width: 85px;">Start date</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Salary: activate to sort column ascending" style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.928571em 20px 0.928571em 0.785714em; text-align: inherit; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; cursor: auto; background: rgb(249, 250, 251); vertical-align: inherit; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); position: relative; border-radius: 0px 0.285714rem 0px 0px; width: 83px;">Salary</th></tr></thead><tfoot style="box-sizing: inherit; box-shadow: none;"><tr style="box-sizing: inherit;"><th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; font-weight: 400; text-align: inherit; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; cursor: auto; border-top-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.15); background: rgb(249, 250, 251); vertical-align: middle; border-left: none; border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0.285714rem;">Name</th><th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; font-weight: 400; text-align: inherit; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; cursor: auto; border-top-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.15); background: rgb(249, 250, 251); vertical-align: middle; border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1);">Position</th><th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; font-weight: 400; text-align: inherit; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; cursor: auto; border-top-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.15); background: rgb(249, 250, 251); vertical-align: middle; border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1);">Office</th><th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; font-weight: 400; text-align: inherit; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; cursor: auto; border-top-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.15); background: rgb(249, 250, 251); vertical-align: middle; border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1);">Age</th><th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; font-weight: 400; text-align: inherit; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; cursor: auto; border-top-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.15); background: rgb(249, 250, 251); vertical-align: middle; border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1);">Start date</th><th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; font-weight: 400; text-align: inherit; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; cursor: auto; border-top-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.15); background: rgb(249, 250, 251); vertical-align: middle; border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); border-radius: 0px 0px 0.285714rem;">Salary</th></tr></tfoot><tbody style="box-sizing: inherit;"><tr role="row" class="odd" style="box-sizing: inherit;"><td class="sorting_1" style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; text-align: inherit; border-top: none; border-left: none;">Airi Satou</td><td style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; text-align: inherit; border-top: none; border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1);">Accountant</td><td style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; text-align: inherit; border-top: none; border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1);">Tokyo</td><td style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; text-align: inherit; border-top: none; border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1);">33</td><td style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; text-align: inherit; border-top: none; border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1);">2008/11/28</td><td style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; text-align: inherit; border-top: none; border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1);">$162,700</td></tr><tr role="row" class="even" style="box-sizing: inherit;"><td class="sorting_1" style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; text-align: inherit; border-top-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); border-left: none;">Angelica Ramos</td><td style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; text-align: inherit; border-top-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1);">Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td><td style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; text-align: inherit; border-top-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1);">London</td><td style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; text-align: inherit; border-top-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1);">47</td><td style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; text-align: inherit; border-top-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1);">2009/10/09</td><td style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; text-align: inherit; border-top-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1);">$1,200,000</td></tr></tbody></table><p style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><br></p><p style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><br></p></div></h2><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Nunc tincidunt, elit non cursus euismod, lacus augue ornare metus, egestas imperdiet nulla nisl quis mauris. Suspendisse a pharetra urna. Morbi dui lectus, pharetra nec elementum eget, vulputate ut nisi. Aliquam accumsan, nulla sed feugiat vehicula, lacus justo semper libero, quis porttitor turpis odio sit amet ligula. Duis dapibus fermentum orci, nec malesuada libero vehicula ut.</span></p><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Integer sodales, urna eget interdum eleifend, nulla nibh laoreet nisl, quis dignissim mauris dolor eget mi. Donec at mauris enim. Duis nisi tellus, adipiscing a convallis quis, tristique vitae risus. Nullam molestie gravida lobortis. Proin ut nibh quis felis auctor ornare. Cras ultricies, nibh at mollis faucibus, justo eros porttitor mi, quis auctor lectus arcu sit amet nunc.</span></p><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Nunc tincidunt, elit non cursus euismod, lacus augue ornare metus, egestas imperdiet nulla nisl quis mauris. Suspendisse a pharetra urna. Morbi dui lectus, pharetra nec elementum eget, vulputate ut nisi. Aliquam accumsan, nulla sed feugiat vehicula, lacus justo semper libero, quis porttitor turpis odio sit amet ligula. Duis dapibus fermentum orci, nec malesuada libero vehicula ut.</span></p><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Integer sodales, urna eget interdum eleifend, nulla nibh laoreet nisl, quis dignissim mauris dolor eget mi. Donec at mauris enim. Duis nisi tellus, adipiscing a convallis quis, tristique vitae risus. Nullam molestie gravida lobortis. Proin ut nibh quis felis auctor ornare. Cras ultricies, nibh at mollis faucibus, justo eros porttitor mi, quis auctor lectus arcu sit amet nunc.</span></p><div><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Nunc tincidunt, elit non cursus euismod, lacus augue ornare metus, egestas imperdiet nulla nisl quis mauris. Suspendisse a pharetra urna. Morbi dui lectus, pharetra nec elementum eget, vulputate ut nisi. Aliquam accumsan, nulla sed feugiat vehicula, lacus justo semper libero, quis porttitor turpis odio sit amet ligula. Duis dapibus fermentum orci, nec malesuada libero vehicula ut.</span></p><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Integer sodales, urna eget interdum eleifend, nulla nibh laoreet nisl, quis dignissim mauris dolor eget mi. Donec at mauris enim. Duis nisi tellus, adipiscing a convallis quis, tristique vitae risus. Nullam molestie gravida lobortis. Proin ut nibh quis felis auctor ornare. Cras ultricies, nibh at mollis faucibus, justo eros porttitor mi, quis auctor lectus arcu sit amet nunc.</span></p></div><div><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Nunc tincidunt, elit non cursus euismod, lacus augue ornare metus, egestas imperdiet nulla nisl quis mauris. Suspendisse a pharetra urna. Morbi dui lectus, pharetra nec elementum eget, vulputate ut nisi. Aliquam accumsan, nulla sed feugiat vehicula, lacus justo semper libero, quis porttitor turpis odio sit amet ligula. Duis dapibus fermentum orci, nec malesuada libero vehicula ut.</span></p><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Integer sodales, urna eget interdum eleifend, nulla nibh laoreet nisl, quis dignissim mauris dolor eget mi. Donec at mauris enim. Duis nisi tellus, adipiscing a convallis quis, tristique vitae risus. Nullam molestie gravida lobortis. Proin ut nibh quis felis auctor ornare. Cras ultricies, nibh at mollis faucibus, justo eros porttitor mi, quis auctor lectus arcu sit amet nunc.</span></p></div><div><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Nunc tincidunt, elit non cursus euismod, lacus augue ornare metus, egestas imperdiet nulla nisl quis mauris. Suspendisse a pharetra urna. Morbi dui lectus, pharetra nec elementum eget, vulputate ut nisi. Aliquam accumsan, nulla sed feugiat vehicula, lacus justo semper libero, quis porttitor turpis odio sit amet ligula. Duis dapibus fermentum orci, nec malesuada libero vehicula ut.</span></p><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Integer sodales, urna eget interdum eleifend, nulla nibh laoreet nisl, quis dignissim mauris dolor eget mi. Donec at mauris enim. Duis nisi tellus, adipiscing a convallis quis, tristique vitae risus. Nullam molestie gravida lobortis. Proin ut nibh quis felis auctor ornare. Cras ultricies, nibh at mollis faucibus, justo eros porttitor mi, quis auctor lectus arcu sit amet nunc.</span></p></div><div><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Nunc tincidunt, elit non cursus euismod, lacus augue ornare metus, egestas imperdiet nulla nisl quis mauris. Suspendisse a pharetra urna. Morbi dui lectus, pharetra nec elementum eget, vulputate ut nisi. Aliquam accumsan, nulla sed feugiat vehicula, lacus justo semper libero, quis porttitor turpis odio sit amet ligula. Duis dapibus fermentum orci, nec malesuada libero vehicula ut.</span></p><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Integer sodales, urna eget interdum eleifend, nulla nibh laoreet nisl, quis dignissim mauris dolor eget mi. Donec at mauris enim. Duis nisi tellus, adipiscing a convallis quis, tristique vitae risus. Nullam molestie gravida lobortis. Proin ut nibh quis felis auctor ornare. Cras ultricies, nibh at mollis faucibus, justo eros porttitor mi, quis auctor lectus arcu sit amet nunc.</span></p></div><div><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Nunc tincidunt, elit non cursus euismod, lacus augue ornare metus, egestas imperdiet nulla nisl quis mauris. Suspendisse a pharetra urna. Morbi dui lectus, pharetra nec elementum eget, vulputate ut nisi. Aliquam accumsan, nulla sed feugiat vehicula, lacus justo semper libero, quis porttitor turpis odio sit amet ligula. Duis dapibus fermentum orci, nec malesuada libero vehicula ut.</span></p><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Integer sodales, urna eget interdum eleifend, nulla nibh laoreet nisl, quis dignissim mauris dolor eget mi. Donec at mauris enim. Duis nisi tellus, adipiscing a convallis quis, tristique vitae risus. Nullam molestie gravida lobortis. Proin ut nibh quis felis auctor ornare. Cras ultricies, nibh at mollis faucibus, justo eros porttitor mi, quis auctor lectus arcu sit amet nunc.</span></p></div><div><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Nunc tincidunt, elit non cursus euismod, lacus augue ornare metus, egestas imperdiet nulla nisl quis mauris. Suspendisse a pharetra urna. Morbi dui lectus, pharetra nec elementum eget, vulputate ut nisi. Aliquam accumsan, nulla sed feugiat vehicula, lacus justo semper libero, quis porttitor turpis odio sit amet ligula. Duis dapibus fermentum orci, nec malesuada libero vehicula ut.</span></p><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Integer sodales, urna eget interdum eleifend, nulla nibh laoreet nisl, quis dignissim mauris dolor eget mi. Donec at mauris enim. Duis nisi tellus, adipiscing a convallis quis, tristique vitae risus. Nullam molestie gravida lobortis. Proin ut nibh quis felis auctor ornare. Cras ultricies, nibh at mollis faucibus, justo eros porttitor mi, quis auctor lectus arcu sit amet nunc.</span></p></div><div><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Nunc tincidunt, elit non cursus euismod, lacus augue ornare metus, egestas imperdiet nulla nisl quis mauris. Suspendisse a pharetra urna. Morbi dui lectus, pharetra nec elementum eget, vulputate ut nisi. Aliquam accumsan, nulla sed feugiat vehicula, lacus justo semper libero, quis porttitor turpis odio sit amet ligula. Duis dapibus fermentum orci, nec malesuada libero vehicula ut.</span></p><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Integer sodales, urna eget interdum eleifend, nulla nibh laoreet nisl, quis dignissim mauris dolor eget mi. Donec at mauris enim. Duis nisi tellus, adipiscing a convallis quis, tristique vitae risus. Nullam molestie gravida lobortis. Proin ut nibh quis felis auctor ornare. Cras ultricies, nibh at mollis faucibus, justo eros porttitor mi, quis auctor lectus arcu sit amet nunc.</span></p></div><div><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Nunc tincidunt, elit non cursus euismod, lacus augue ornare metus, egestas imperdiet nulla nisl quis mauris. Suspendisse a pharetra urna. Morbi dui lectus, pharetra nec elementum eget, vulputate ut nisi. Aliquam accumsan, nulla sed feugiat vehicula, lacus justo semper libero, quis porttitor turpis odio sit amet ligula. Duis dapibus fermentum orci, nec malesuada libero vehicula ut.</span></p><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Integer sodales, urna eget interdum eleifend, nulla nibh laoreet nisl, quis dignissim mauris dolor eget mi. Donec at mauris enim. Duis nisi tellus, adipiscing a convallis quis, tristique vitae risus. Nullam molestie gravida lobortis. Proin ut nibh quis felis auctor ornare. Cras ultricies, nibh at mollis faucibus, justo eros porttitor mi, quis auctor lectus arcu sit amet nunc.</span></p></div><div><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Nunc tincidunt, elit non cursus euismod, lacus augue ornare metus, egestas imperdiet nulla nisl quis mauris. Suspendisse a pharetra urna. Morbi dui lectus, pharetra nec elementum eget, vulputate ut nisi. Aliquam accumsan, nulla sed feugiat vehicula, lacus justo semper libero, quis porttitor turpis odio sit amet ligula. Duis dapibus fermentum orci, nec malesuada libero vehicula ut.</span></p><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Integer sodales, urna eget interdum eleifend, nulla nibh laoreet nisl, quis dignissim mauris dolor eget mi. Donec at mauris enim. Duis nisi tellus, adipiscing a convallis quis, tristique vitae risus. Nullam molestie gravida lobortis. Proin ut nibh quis felis auctor ornare. Cras ultricies, nibh at mollis faucibus, justo eros porttitor mi, quis auctor lectus arcu sit amet nunc.</span></p></div><div><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Nunc tincidunt, elit non cursus euismod, lacus augue ornare metus, egestas imperdiet nulla nisl quis mauris. Suspendisse a pharetra urna. Morbi dui lectus, pharetra nec elementum eget, vulputate ut nisi. Aliquam accumsan, nulla sed feugiat vehicula, lacus justo semper libero, quis porttitor turpis odio sit amet ligula. Duis dapibus fermentum orci, nec malesuada libero vehicula ut.</span></p><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Integer sodales, urna eget interdum eleifend, nulla nibh laoreet nisl, quis dignissim mauris dolor eget mi. Donec at mauris enim. Duis nisi tellus, adipiscing a convallis quis, tristique vitae risus. Nullam molestie gravida lobortis. Proin ut nibh quis felis auctor ornare. Cras ultricies, nibh at mollis faucibus, justo eros porttitor mi, quis auctor lectus arcu sit amet nunc.</span></p></div><div><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Nunc tincidunt, elit non cursus euismod, lacus augue ornare metus, egestas imperdiet nulla nisl quis mauris. Suspendisse a pharetra urna. Morbi dui lectus, pharetra nec elementum eget, vulputate ut nisi. Aliquam accumsan, nulla sed feugiat vehicula, lacus justo semper libero, quis porttitor turpis odio sit amet ligula. Duis dapibus fermentum orci, nec malesuada libero vehicula ut.</span></p><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Integer sodales, urna eget interdum eleifend, nulla nibh laoreet nisl, quis dignissim mauris dolor eget mi. Donec at mauris enim. Duis nisi tellus, adipiscing a convallis quis, tristique vitae risus. Nullam molestie gravida lobortis. Proin ut nibh quis felis auctor ornare. Cras ultricies, nibh at mollis faucibus, justo eros porttitor mi, quis auctor lectus arcu sit amet nunc.</span></p></div><div><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Nunc tincidunt, elit non cursus euismod, lacus augue ornare metus, egestas imperdiet nulla nisl quis mauris. Suspendisse a pharetra urna. Morbi dui lectus, pharetra nec elementum eget, vulputate ut nisi. Aliquam accumsan, nulla sed feugiat vehicula, lacus justo semper libero, quis porttitor turpis odio sit amet ligula. Duis dapibus fermentum orci, nec malesuada libero vehicula ut.</span></p><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Integer sodales, urna eget interdum eleifend, nulla nibh laoreet nisl, quis dignissim mauris dolor eget mi. Donec at mauris enim. Duis nisi tellus, adipiscing a convallis quis, tristique vitae risus. Nullam molestie gravida lobortis. Proin ut nibh quis felis auctor ornare. Cras ultricies, nibh at mollis faucibus, justo eros porttitor mi, quis auctor lectus arcu sit amet nunc.</span></p></div><p><br></p></page>
```

Comment: Nice try, but if `child.height() >= pageHeight` your code will fall into the endless recursion producing empty pages.

Comment: Yup, will fix it if OP verifies this is what he needs :D

Comment: @HouyNarun check added explanation, inifinite loop fix and page number

Answer (score 2):

### Preamble

I looked at other answers I've found on the internet. However, after implementing them, I could notice that it takes some seconds, not just milliseconds but real seconds, until the script is finished. Meanwhile, the whole GUI of the page is blocked. Therefore, I created my own solution which has a performance of 10ms per page (at least on my computer).

### The Idea

We are facing the problem that we do not necessarily have a monospace font, so we cannot calculate the text based on `line-height`. We need to take a different approach. So I decided to try a method which you can find on various websites if google how to get the number of visible characters. The idea is to write all the letters into a string. Then, in a loop, you create an element, e.g. a `span`, and add it to the container. You calculate the `offsetTop` of this span and if it is larger than the `offsetHeight` of the wrapper, the end of the container is reached. Hence, you only need to count how many `span`-elements you have got in the container to determine the maximum number of characters which fit into the container.

Usually, the `span`-element consists of only one character which is a very slow solution. That is why I decided to do it differently: I start by adding 800 characters to the `span`-element until these blocks do not fit anymore. Then, I add only `800 / 4 = 200` characters (in my tests these were the best values for your container concerning the performance) to the `span`-elements and fill the container again. I continue decreasing the character amount of a `span`-element until it equals one.

This is my function to determine the number of visible characters:

```
function countVisibleChars(elem, text) {
  var visibleChars = 0;
  for (var charNum = 800; charNum > 0; charNum = Math.floor(charNum / 4)) {
    for (var i = visibleChars; i < text.length; i += charNum) {
      var tempSpan = document.createElement('span');
      tempSpan.innerText = text.substring(i, i + charNum);
      elem.appendChild(tempSpan);
      visibleChars += charNum;
      if (tempSpan.offsetTop >= elem.offsetHeight) {
        elem.removeChild(elem.lastChild);
        elem.removeChild(elem.lastChild);
        visibleChars -= 2 * charNum;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return visibleChars;
}
```

### Use of this function

To use this function properly for your needs, you have to call it multiple times until all characters are assigned to a `page`-element. You should use a loop like this:

```
var initialPage = document.getElementsByClassName('a4')[0];
var text = initialPage.innerText;
var charSumInitialPage = countVisibleChars(initialPage, text);
var charSum = charSumInitialPage;

while (charSum < text.length) {
  var newPage = document.createElement('page');
  initialPage.innerText = '';
  var chars = countVisibleChars(initialPage, text.substring(charSum));
  charSum += chars;
  newPage.innerText = text.substring(charSum - chars, charSum);
  document.body.appendChild(newPage);
}
```

Note that you cannot use the created elements to calculate the maximum number of characters. Always use the initial `page`-element.

### Conclusion

By using this approach, we can create the right number of pages and assign the characters to them without having to wait for a longer time period. Here is an example to illustrate that it works:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var initialPage = document.getElementsByClassName('a4')[0];
  var pageNumber = 1;
  var text = initialPage.innerText;

  var charSumInitialPage = countVisibleChars(initialPage, text);
  var charSum = charSumInitialPage;

  while (charSum < text.length) {
    ++pageNumber;
    var newPage = document.createElement('page');
    newPage.setAttribute('size', 'A4');
    newPage.setAttribute('class', 'a4');
    newPage.dataset.pages = pageNumber;
    initialPage.innerText = '';
    var chars = countVisibleChars(initialPage, text.substring(charSum));
    charSum += chars;
    newPage.innerText = text.substring(charSum - chars, charSum);
    document.body.appendChild(newPage);
  }

  initialPage.innerText = text.substring(0, charSumInitialPage);
}, false);

function countVisibleChars(elem, text) {
  var visibleChars = 0;
  for (var charNum = 800; charNum > 0; charNum = Math.floor(charNum / 4)) {
    for (var i = visibleChars; i < text.length; i += charNum) {
      var tempSpan = document.createElement('span');
      tempSpan.innerText = text.substring(i, i + charNum);
      elem.appendChild(tempSpan);
      visibleChars += charNum;
      if (tempSpan.offsetTop >= elem.offsetHeight) {
        elem.removeChild(elem.lastChild);
        elem.removeChild(elem.lastChild);
        visibleChars -= 2 * charNum;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return visibleChars;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: rgb(204, 204, 204);
}

span {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  line-height: inherit !important;
}

page {
  background: white;
  display: block;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

page[size="A4"] {
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
  padding: 20px;
}

@media print {  
  body,
  page {
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<page class="a4" size="A4">
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
  one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
  et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
  1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English
  versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor
  at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from
  sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem
  ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced
  in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over
  2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered
  the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance.
  The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum
  et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical
  Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites
  of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the
  theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested.
  Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply
  random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from
  a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero,
  written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since
  the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
  one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
  et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
  1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English
  versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor
  at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from
  sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem
  ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced
  in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over
  2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered
  the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance.
  The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum
  et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical
  Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites
  of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the
  theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested.
  Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply
  random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from
  a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero,
  written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since
  the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
  one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
  et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
  1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English
  versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor
  at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from
  sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem
  ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced
  in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over
  2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered
  the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance.
  The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum
  et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical
  Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites
  of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the
  theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested.
  Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply
  random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from
  a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero,
  written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since
  the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
  one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
  et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
  1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English
  versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor
  at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from
  sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem
  ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced
  in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over
  2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered
  the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance.
  The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum
  et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical
  Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites
  of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the
  theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested.
  Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply
  random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from
  a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero,
  written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since
  the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
</page>
```

For a longer text, please look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/srtqb7vx/) fiddle. I hope, you like this solution.

Comment: Thanks very much, the loading time and everything is really fine, until `++pageNumber;` is not yet showing at the bottom of each page, could you please add `pageNumber` include page number formatting (eg, page 1 of 3) and position (bottom left, bottom center, bottom right)? so that I can accept it as the only answer, thanks.

Comment: I will do that and I will also try to try to make HTML work, but please give me some days as my free time is limited.

Answer (score 2):

My 50 cents.
Please let me know if you **really** want "to split at the exact overflowing character", not at the whole word.

```js
var observer = new MutationObserver(cl);
var e = document.querySelector('page');
var i = document.createElement('div');
i.innerHTML = e.innerHTML;
var html = i.innerHTML.split(/\s+/);
e.innerHTML = '';
e.appendChild(i);
nextPage();

function nextPage() {
  if (i.scrollHeight > i.offsetHeight) {
    var c = document.createElement('page');
    c.setAttribute('size', 'A4');
    c = e.parentNode.insertBefore(c, e);
    ci = document.createElement('div');
    c.appendChild(ci);
    var d = html.length * i.offsetHeight / i.scrollHeight | 0;
    observer.observe(ci, {childList: !0, subtree: !0});
    ci.innerHTML = html.slice(0, d).join(' ');
  } else e.innerHTML = i.innerHTML;
}

function cl(ml) {
  for (var m of ml) {
    if (m.type === 'childList') {
      var ci = m.target;
      var d = ci.innerHTML.split(/\s+/).length;
      if (ci.scrollHeight > ci.offsetHeight) {
        ci.innerHTML = html.slice(0, d - 1).join(' ');
      } else {
        ci.parentNode.innerHTML = ci.innerHTML;
        i.innerHTML = html.slice(d).join(' ');
        html = html.slice(d);
        observer.disconnect();
        nextPage();
      }
    }
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  background: rgb(204, 204, 204);
}

page {
  background: white;
  display: block;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

page[size="A4"] {
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
  padding: 1cm;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

page div {
  height: 100%;
}

@media print {
  body,
  page {
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<page size="A4"> Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. </page>
```

Comment: Thanks, if content in <page> is the HTML code, does it render content correctly in browser ? thanks.

Comment: @HouyNarun, Since HTML code can include nested elements, images, tables, iframes etc. it may not render correrctly (as any other solution on this page). Rendering of HTML requires more complex approach.

Comment: could you please update your answer to support html code. it’s my mistake that I not use my real practice in question actually in real Practice the content is all html saved from text editor for rendering on browser,  thanks so much.

Comment: @HouyNarun, You're asking for a huge amount of work which is really out of Stackoverflow scope. It is neither a bugfix nor a suggestion. So I won't write it for you. It would be better if you write the code yourself. But ask for a help at Stackoverflow if you've faced a problem.

Comment: thanks so much suggestion, I have my code by myself starting from solution from here.

Comment: `Word-break:break-word` needed to fulfill requirement

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to know your `line-height` and `font-size`, then you can know lines per height and chars per line. Then it's easy to calculate maximum amount of characters for a page, take a 20 chars buffer (probably not necessary) and cut everything after. That's very easy to calculate when all chars and fonts are the same heights and sizes. And becomes very complicated when they're not.

Comment: knowing line-height and font size how many line my text currently has, and  how I know how many lines fit enough per one page ? As you mentioned, it was quite difficult if it has different font and line height. Thank.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to work with a **span** or a **div** than with a **text node** if you want to get some sense of position of your text. What you could do is put the text in a span and then you can compare the offsets and know more about the layout.

Once you have this done, if the format and content are variable, you're pretty much stuck with modifying the content and checking as you go to see if it meets your criteria.

For example you could transfer the text letter by letter to a new page and see after each letter if the layout is ok. Like this:

```js
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('a4')[0];

// put your text in a span
var newSpan = document.createElement('span');
newSpan.append(document.getElementsByClassName('a4')[0].childNodes[0])
element.append(newSpan)


if (newSpan.offsetHeight > element.offsetHeight) {

  // create the new page if the span is bigger than then page
  var newPage = document.createElement('page');
  newPage.setAttribute('size', 'A4');
  newPage.setAttribute('class', 'a4');
  newPage.dataset.pages = 2;
  document.body.appendChild(newPage);
  var newNewSpan = document.createElement('span');
  newPage.append(newNewSpan);
  
  // counter is there just to control the while loop, not necessary
  var counter = 0;
  while((newSpan.offsetHeight +  newSpan.offsetTop) > (element.offsetHeight + element.offsetTop) && counter < 20000){
  counter++;
  
  // you move the last letter of the first page to the second page until the first span is smaller than the page. That way you find the exact letter that overflows. You could work with word as well or find a way to move bigger portions at a time so it's faster.
  newNewSpan.innerText = newSpan.innerText.slice(newSpan.innerText.length -1, newSpan.innerText.length) + newNewSpan.innerText;
  newSpan.innerText = newSpan.innerText.substr(0, newSpan.innerText.length - 1);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: rgb(204, 204, 204);
}

page {
  background: white;
  display: block;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

page[size="A4"] {
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
  padding: 20px;
}

@media print {
  body,
  page {
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<page size="A4" class="a4">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance.
  The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested.
  Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance.
  The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical
  Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested.
  Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem
  ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced
  in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over
  2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered
  the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance.
  The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum
  et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
</page>
```