# Insert page breaks dynamically based on content overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have a large webpage generated through many Vue components. The rendered HTML structure is somewhat similar to this:

```
<header></header>
<element1></element1>
<element2></element2>
<element3></element3>
<table></table>
<element4></element4>
<footer></footer>
```

I want to print this nicely on an A5 page having `header` and `footer` repeated on every printed page. I've tried this with 2 approaches:

Converting HTML structure into page containers and splitting elements based on total `clientHeight`. Something like

```
<section class="page">
    <header></header>
    <element1></element1>
    <element2></element2>
    <element3></element3>
    <footer></footer>
</section>
<section class="page">
    <header></header>
    <table></table>
    <element4></element4>
    <footer></footer>
</section>
```

Or, Adding CSS page break properties to `header` and dynamically inserting at content overflow locations. For example

```
<header></header>
<element1></element1>
<element2></element2>
<element3></element3>
<footer></footer>
<header style="page-break-before: always"></header>
<table></table>
<element4></element4>
<footer></footer>
```

The DOM traversal to find overflow point looks like

```
var availHeight = 20;    // Height of A5 page - tolerance
var body = document.querySelector('body');
var initialWidth = body.style.width;
body.style.width = '14.85cm';

if (body.clientHeight > availHeight) {    // if content exceeds page height
    var scrollHeight = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < body.children.length; i++) {
        var child = body.children[i];
        scrollHeight += child.clientHeight;

        if (scrollHeight > availHeight) {    // if children traversed till now make up to the height of page
            if (child.clientHeight < availHeight) {
                child.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '"page break html here..."');
                scrollHeight = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
body.style.width = initialWidth;
```

However, both approaches give inaccurate results while printing.

CSS `@page` is not supported by Safari, hence cannot be useful.

`display: table-header-group` and `table-footer-group` doesn't work either.

**Is there a different cross-browser solution to achieve nicely printed pages with repeating headers and footers and not clipping/overlapping any content, or if the DOM traversal code can be improved to be more generic and stable? Can things be corrected or simplified here?**

Thanks in advance. I haven't reached a satisfactory workaround or solution for this problem.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle of this issue with a sample content?

Comment: @weBBer I couldn't do that because the behaviour of the problem is different across browsers and fiddle doesn't give a print option only for content.

Comment: Is the header and footer content same.?

Comment: No, header and footer can be different.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this qualifies for a separate answer or should just be a comment with some (hopefully useful) tips.

So... this is a battle web developers have long fought. You can find various answers under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/how-to-use-html-to-print-header-and-footer-on-every-printed-page-of-a-document), which this question actually seems to be a duplicate of (somewhat).

*Disclaimer: I can't test the techniques mentioned on iOS, Safari nor IE myself atm. They're more of a recollection of my previous experiences and knowledge gathered from SO posts and various articles' comment threads.*

I'll try to provide some pointers and techniques to get you slightly closer to full browser support, but there are no promises until `@print` is fully supported :/

1. Fixed positioning. For whatever reason, browsers repeat the fixed elements in printed pages. The hard part is tweaking your page margins so that your header and footer don't overlap with page content, but then you should be golden. It's not easy since even with `@page` support, the page margin also pushes down the fixed content. And without support, you'd have to resolve to some `display: table` hacks maybe. I've replicated the `fixed` solution in a simple example (I inlined the CSS so you could open it in a separate HTML file locally for easier testing):

https://jsfiddle.net/vjvu8uox/

2. `@media print` is something you could look into alongside `@print`, since it's supported since [CSS2](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/). It doesn't provide the same powerful selectors, but allows you to tweak your styles slightly for print-specific purposes.

   > "The ‘print’ and ‘screen’ media types are defined in HTML4. The complete list of media types in HTML4 is: ‘aural’, ‘braille’, ‘handheld’, ‘print’, ‘projection’, ‘screen’, ‘tty’, ‘tv’. CSS2 defines the same list, deprecates ‘aural’ and adds ‘embossed’ and ‘speech’. Also, ‘all’ is used to indicate that the style sheet applies to all media types."
3. Tables. A lot of browsers position the `thead` and `tfoot` elements at the top and bottom of every page on print. This works if your `thead` and `tfoot` **don't** contain multiple `tr` elements. The support for this landed in Chrome this March (2018). The useful keywords for this are:

   ```
   thead { display: table-header-group; }

   tfoot { display: table-footer-group; }
   ```

I'm wondering if you could maybe combine 1. and 3. to firstly position your header and footer with `fixed` so they'd repeat and then maybe create empty elements to act as `table-header-group` and `table-footer-group`, which could provide paddings for the fixed elements?

---

I'll quickly also address your traversal script by saying that you might want to account for your Vue's app container (unless you've mounted your Vue instance to the body element, which is considered somewhat of a bad practise) and all its nested children. In that sense, @MunimMunna's jQuery snippet serves you better. I'd rewrite it as vanilla JS and using semi-modern utility methods, we could easily fix the Safari support for that script (I do not have the time right now, but can look into it coming Monday when I'm on my work rig/Mac to test it on Safari).

Best of luck in your print-support endeavours!

Comment: Fixed `position` and/or `table-header-group` elements don't repeat in Safari. BTW thanks for your effort.

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate... I'll try and make the jQuery snippet work on Safari then on Monday : )

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar task [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48733799/how-to-create-new-page-element-for-exceed-content/48805745#48805745), but it was just for formatting the pages to view in a multi-page design. Using similar approach we can implement it for printing with added header and footer. Let me know if it works for you and if you need any help.

```js
$(function(){
  function printFormat($contentElement){
    //Preparing Temporary Page
   var $printWrapper=$('.printWrapper').empty();
    var $tempA5=$('<div class="page-a5">').appendTo($printWrapper);
    $contentElement.clone().children().appendTo($tempA5);
    var $header = $tempA5.find('.header'), $footer = $tempA5.find('.footer');
    var pageHeight = $tempA5.height(), headerHeight = $header.height(), footerHeight = $footer.height();
    $header.remove();$footer.remove();
    //Generating Pages
    var $pageA5=$('<div class="page-a5">').appendTo($printWrapper).append($header.clone());
    var $pagefooter=$footer.clone().appendTo($pageA5),$bottomLine=$('<div>').appendTo($pageA5);
    var $elements=$tempA5.children();
    var i=-1, totalChildren=$elements.length;
    while(++i<totalChildren){
     var $element=$elements.eq(i);
      var $element_copy=$element.clone().insertBefore($pagefooter);
      if($bottomLine[0].offsetTop>pageHeight) {
        $pageA5=$('<div class="page-a5">').appendTo($printWrapper).append($header.clone());
        $pagefooter=$footer.clone().appendTo($pageA5);
        $bottomLine=$('<div>').appendTo($pageA5);
        $element_copy.insertBefore($pagefooter);
      }
    }
    $tempA5.remove();
    $printWrapper.find('.footer').each(function(i,el){
     $(el).css("marginTop",pageHeight-el.nextSibling.offsetTop);
    });
    $contentElement.hide();
  }
  printFormat($("#contents"));
});
```

```css
.page-a5{
    position: relative;
    width: 720px;
    height: 1068px;
    margin: auto;
}
.header{
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: orange;
}
.footer{
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: blue;
}

@media print {
  body,
  page {
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="printWrapper"></div>
<div id="contents">
    <div class="header">Header :)</div>
<p><span style="color: inherit; font-family: inherit; font-size: 14px;"></span></p><h2 class="entry-title fusion-post-title" data-fontsize="18" data-lineheight="27" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 28px; font-size: 18px; font-family: museo-slab-300, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 27px; padding-bottom: 0px;">Blog Image Post</h2><h2><p style="text-align: center; color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><img src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Universal-Placeholder-Text-Lorem-Ipsum-Generator-getlorem.jpg" style="width: 425px;"><span style="color: rgb(107, 113, 122);"><br></span></p><p style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><span style="color: rgb(107, 113, 122);">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(107, 113, 122);">one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source.</span></p><h3 style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><ul style="box-sizing: inherit; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 15px;"><li style="box-sizing: inherit;">Item</li><li style="box-sizing: inherit;">Item</li><li style="box-sizing: inherit;">Item</li><li style="box-sizing: inherit;">Item</li></ul></h3><h3 style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; margin-bottom: 20px;">Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of&nbsp; "de Finibus Bonorum&nbsp;<span style="color: rgb(107, 113, 122);">et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance.</span><br></h3><ol style="box-sizing: inherit; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 15px;"><li style="box-sizing: inherit;">First item</li><li style="box-sizing: inherit;">Second item</li><li style="box-sizing: inherit;">Third item</li><li style="box-sizing: inherit;">Fourth item</li></ol><p style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><span style="color: rgb(107, 113, 122);">The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section</span><span style="color: rgb(107, 113, 122);">&nbsp; 1.10.32.&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(107, 113, 122);">The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(107, 113, 122);">versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</span></p><table id="example" class="ui celled table dataTable" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="grid" aria-describedby="example_info" style="box-sizing: inherit; border-collapse: separate; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); margin: 0px; border: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.15); box-shadow: none; border-radius: 0.285714rem; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); font-size: 14px; font-family: Lato, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><thead style="box-sizing: inherit; box-shadow: none;"><tr role="row" style="box-sizing: inherit;"><th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Name: activate to sort column descending" style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.928571em 20px 0.928571em 0.785714em; text-align: inherit; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; cursor: auto; background: rgb(249, 250, 251); vertical-align: inherit; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); border-left: none; position: relative; border-radius: 0.285714rem 0px 0px; width: 137px;">Name</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Position: activate to sort column ascending" style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.928571em 20px 0.928571em 0.785714em; text-align: inherit; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; cursor: auto; background: rgb(249, 250, 251); vertical-align: inherit; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); position: relative; width: 224px;">Position</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Office: activate to sort column ascending" style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.928571em 20px 0.928571em 0.785714em; text-align: inherit; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; cursor: auto; background: rgb(249, 250, 251); vertical-align: inherit; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); position: relative; width: 104px;">Office</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Age: activate to sort column ascending" style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.928571em 20px 0.928571em 0.785714em; text-align: inherit; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; cursor: auto; background: rgb(249, 250, 251); vertical-align: inherit; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); position: relative; width: 39px;">Age</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Start date: activate to sort column ascending" style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.928571em 20px 0.928571em 0.785714em; text-align: inherit; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; cursor: auto; background: rgb(249, 250, 251); vertical-align: inherit; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); position: relative; width: 85px;">Start date</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Salary: activate to sort column ascending" style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.928571em 20px 0.928571em 0.785714em; text-align: inherit; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; cursor: auto; background: rgb(249, 250, 251); vertical-align: inherit; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); position: relative; border-radius: 0px 0.285714rem 0px 0px; width: 83px;">Salary</th></tr></thead><tfoot style="box-sizing: inherit; box-shadow: none;"><tr style="box-sizing: inherit;"><th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; font-weight: 400; text-align: inherit; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; cursor: auto; border-top-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.15); background: rgb(249, 250, 251); vertical-align: middle; border-left: none; border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0.285714rem;">Name</th><th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; font-weight: 400; text-align: inherit; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; cursor: auto; border-top-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.15); background: rgb(249, 250, 251); vertical-align: middle; border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1);">Position</th><th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; font-weight: 400; text-align: inherit; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; cursor: auto; border-top-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.15); background: rgb(249, 250, 251); vertical-align: middle; border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1);">Office</th><th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; font-weight: 400; text-align: inherit; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; cursor: auto; border-top-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.15); background: rgb(249, 250, 251); vertical-align: middle; border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1);">Age</th><th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; font-weight: 400; text-align: inherit; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; cursor: auto; border-top-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.15); background: rgb(249, 250, 251); vertical-align: middle; border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1);">Start date</th><th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; font-weight: 400; text-align: inherit; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; cursor: auto; border-top-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.15); background: rgb(249, 250, 251); vertical-align: middle; border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); border-radius: 0px 0px 0.285714rem;">Salary</th></tr></tfoot><tbody style="box-sizing: inherit;"><tr role="row" class="odd" style="box-sizing: inherit;"><td class="sorting_1" style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; text-align: inherit; border-top: none; border-left: none;">Airi Satou</td><td style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; text-align: inherit; border-top: none; border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1);">Accountant</td><td style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; text-align: inherit; border-top: none; border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1);">Tokyo</td><td style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; text-align: inherit; border-top: none; border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1);">33</td><td style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; text-align: inherit; border-top: none; border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1);">2008/11/28</td><td style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; text-align: inherit; border-top: none; border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1);">$162,700</td></tr><tr role="row" class="even" style="box-sizing: inherit;"><td class="sorting_1" style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; text-align: inherit; border-top-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); border-left: none;">Angelica Ramos</td><td style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; text-align: inherit; border-top-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1);">Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td><td style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; text-align: inherit; border-top-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1);">London</td><td style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; text-align: inherit; border-top-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1);">47</td><td style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; text-align: inherit; border-top-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1);">2009/10/09</td><td style="box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0.785714em; transition: background 0.1s ease, color 0.1s ease; text-align: inherit; border-top-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1); border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1);">$1,200,000</td></tr></tbody></table><p style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><br></p><p style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><br></p></h2><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Nunc tincidunt, elit non cursus euismod, lacus augue ornare metus, egestas imperdiet nulla nisl quis mauris. Suspendisse a pharetra urna. Morbi dui lectus, pharetra nec elementum eget, vulputate ut nisi. Aliquam accumsan, nulla sed feugiat vehicula, lacus justo semper libero, quis porttitor turpis odio sit amet ligula. Duis dapibus fermentum orci, nec malesuada libero vehicula ut.</span></p><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Integer sodales, urna eget interdum eleifend, nulla nibh laoreet nisl, quis dignissim mauris dolor eget mi. Donec at mauris enim. Duis nisi tellus, adipiscing a convallis quis, tristique vitae risus. Nullam molestie gravida lobortis. Proin ut nibh quis felis auctor ornare. Cras ultricies, nibh at mollis faucibus, justo eros porttitor mi, quis auctor lectus arcu sit amet nunc.</span></p><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Nunc tincidunt, elit non cursus euismod, lacus augue ornare metus, egestas imperdiet nulla nisl quis mauris. Suspendisse a pharetra urna. Morbi dui lectus, pharetra nec elementum eget, vulputate ut nisi. Aliquam accumsan, nulla sed feugiat vehicula, lacus justo semper libero, quis porttitor turpis odio sit amet ligula. Duis dapibus fermentum orci, nec malesuada libero vehicula ut.</span></p><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Integer sodales, urna eget interdum eleifend, nulla nibh laoreet nisl, quis dignissim mauris dolor eget mi. Donec at mauris enim. Duis nisi tellus, adipiscing a convallis quis, tristique vitae risus. Nullam molestie gravida lobortis. Proin ut nibh quis felis auctor ornare. Cras ultricies, nibh at mollis faucibus, justo eros porttitor mi, quis auctor lectus arcu sit amet nunc.</span></p><div><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Nunc tincidunt, elit non cursus euismod, lacus augue ornare metus, egestas imperdiet nulla nisl quis mauris. Suspendisse a pharetra urna. Morbi dui lectus, pharetra nec elementum eget, vulputate ut nisi. Aliquam accumsan, nulla sed feugiat vehicula, lacus justo semper libero, quis porttitor turpis odio sit amet ligula. Duis dapibus fermentum orci, nec malesuada libero vehicula ut.</span></p><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Integer sodales, urna eget interdum eleifend, nulla nibh laoreet nisl, quis dignissim mauris dolor eget mi. Donec at mauris enim. Duis nisi tellus, adipiscing a convallis quis, tristique vitae risus. Nullam molestie gravida lobortis. Proin ut nibh quis felis auctor ornare. Cras ultricies, nibh at mollis faucibus, justo eros porttitor mi, quis auctor lectus arcu sit amet nunc.</span></p></div><div><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Nunc tincidunt, elit non cursus euismod, lacus augue ornare metus, egestas imperdiet nulla nisl quis mauris. Suspendisse a pharetra urna. Morbi dui lectus, pharetra nec elementum eget, vulputate ut nisi. Aliquam accumsan, nulla sed feugiat vehicula, lacus justo semper libero, quis porttitor turpis odio sit amet ligula. Duis dapibus fermentum orci, nec malesuada libero vehicula ut.</span></p><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Integer sodales, urna eget interdum eleifend, nulla nibh laoreet nisl, quis dignissim mauris dolor eget mi. Donec at mauris enim. Duis nisi tellus, adipiscing a convallis quis, tristique vitae risus. Nullam molestie gravida lobortis. Proin ut nibh quis felis auctor ornare. Cras ultricies, nibh at mollis faucibus, justo eros porttitor mi, quis auctor lectus arcu sit amet nunc.</span></p></div><div><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Nunc tincidunt, elit non cursus euismod, lacus augue ornare metus, egestas imperdiet nulla nisl quis mauris. Suspendisse a pharetra urna. Morbi dui lectus, pharetra nec elementum eget, vulputate ut nisi. Aliquam accumsan, nulla sed feugiat vehicula, lacus justo semper libero, quis porttitor turpis odio sit amet ligula. Duis dapibus fermentum orci, nec malesuada libero vehicula ut.</span></p><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Integer sodales, urna eget interdum eleifend, nulla nibh laoreet nisl, quis dignissim mauris dolor eget mi. Donec at mauris enim. Duis nisi tellus, adipiscing a convallis quis, tristique vitae risus. Nullam molestie gravida lobortis. Proin ut nibh quis felis auctor ornare. Cras ultricies, nibh at mollis faucibus, justo eros porttitor mi, quis auctor lectus arcu sit amet nunc.</span></p></div><div><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Nunc tincidunt, elit non cursus euismod, lacus augue ornare metus, egestas imperdiet nulla nisl quis mauris. Suspendisse a pharetra urna. Morbi dui lectus, pharetra nec elementum eget, vulputate ut nisi. Aliquam accumsan, nulla sed feugiat vehicula, lacus justo semper libero, quis porttitor turpis odio sit amet ligula. Duis dapibus fermentum orci, nec malesuada libero vehicula ut.</span></p><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Integer sodales, urna eget interdum eleifend, nulla nibh laoreet nisl, quis dignissim mauris dolor eget mi. Donec at mauris enim. Duis nisi tellus, adipiscing a convallis quis, tristique vitae risus. Nullam molestie gravida lobortis. Proin ut nibh quis felis auctor ornare. Cras ultricies, nibh at mollis faucibus, justo eros porttitor mi, quis auctor lectus arcu sit amet nunc.</span></p></div><div><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Nunc tincidunt, elit non cursus euismod, lacus augue ornare metus, egestas imperdiet nulla nisl quis mauris. Suspendisse a pharetra urna. Morbi dui lectus, pharetra nec elementum eget, vulputate ut nisi. Aliquam accumsan, nulla sed feugiat vehicula, lacus justo semper libero, quis porttitor turpis odio sit amet ligula. Duis dapibus fermentum orci, nec malesuada libero vehicula ut.</span></p><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Integer sodales, urna eget interdum eleifend, nulla nibh laoreet nisl, quis dignissim mauris dolor eget mi. Donec at mauris enim. Duis nisi tellus, adipiscing a convallis quis, tristique vitae risus. Nullam molestie gravida lobortis. Proin ut nibh quis felis auctor ornare. Cras ultricies, nibh at mollis faucibus, justo eros porttitor mi, quis auctor lectus arcu sit amet nunc.</span></p></div><div><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Nunc tincidunt, elit non cursus euismod, lacus augue ornare metus, egestas imperdiet nulla nisl quis mauris. Suspendisse a pharetra urna. Morbi dui lectus, pharetra nec elementum eget, vulputate ut nisi. Aliquam accumsan, nulla sed feugiat vehicula, lacus justo semper libero, quis porttitor turpis odio sit amet ligula. Duis dapibus fermentum orci, nec malesuada libero vehicula ut.</span></p><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Integer sodales, urna eget interdum eleifend, nulla nibh laoreet nisl, quis dignissim mauris dolor eget mi. Donec at mauris enim. Duis nisi tellus, adipiscing a convallis quis, tristique vitae risus. Nullam molestie gravida lobortis. Proin ut nibh quis felis auctor ornare. Cras ultricies, nibh at mollis faucibus, justo eros porttitor mi, quis auctor lectus arcu sit amet nunc.</span></p></div><div><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Nunc tincidunt, elit non cursus euismod, lacus augue ornare metus, egestas imperdiet nulla nisl quis mauris. Suspendisse a pharetra urna. Morbi dui lectus, pharetra nec elementum eget, vulputate ut nisi. Aliquam accumsan, nulla sed feugiat vehicula, lacus justo semper libero, quis porttitor turpis odio sit amet ligula. Duis dapibus fermentum orci, nec malesuada libero vehicula ut.</span></p><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Integer sodales, urna eget interdum eleifend, nulla nibh laoreet nisl, quis dignissim mauris dolor eget mi. Donec at mauris enim. Duis nisi tellus, adipiscing a convallis quis, tristique vitae risus. Nullam molestie gravida lobortis. Proin ut nibh quis felis auctor ornare. Cras ultricies, nibh at mollis faucibus, justo eros porttitor mi, quis auctor lectus arcu sit amet nunc.</span></p></div><div><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Nunc tincidunt, elit non cursus euismod, lacus augue ornare metus, egestas imperdiet nulla nisl quis mauris. Suspendisse a pharetra urna. Morbi dui lectus, pharetra nec elementum eget, vulputate ut nisi. Aliquam accumsan, nulla sed feugiat vehicula, lacus justo semper libero, quis porttitor turpis odio sit amet ligula. Duis dapibus fermentum orci, nec malesuada libero vehicula ut.</span></p><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Integer sodales, urna eget interdum eleifend, nulla nibh laoreet nisl, quis dignissim mauris dolor eget mi. Donec at mauris enim. Duis nisi tellus, adipiscing a convallis quis, tristique vitae risus. Nullam molestie gravida lobortis. Proin ut nibh quis felis auctor ornare. Cras ultricies, nibh at mollis faucibus, justo eros porttitor mi, quis auctor lectus arcu sit amet nunc.</span></p></div><div><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Nunc tincidunt, elit non cursus euismod, lacus augue ornare metus, egestas imperdiet nulla nisl quis mauris. Suspendisse a pharetra urna. Morbi dui lectus, pharetra nec elementum eget, vulputate ut nisi. Aliquam accumsan, nulla sed feugiat vehicula, lacus justo semper libero, quis porttitor turpis odio sit amet ligula. Duis dapibus fermentum orci, nec malesuada libero vehicula ut.</span></p><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Integer sodales, urna eget interdum eleifend, nulla nibh laoreet nisl, quis dignissim mauris dolor eget mi. Donec at mauris enim. Duis nisi tellus, adipiscing a convallis quis, tristique vitae risus. Nullam molestie gravida lobortis. Proin ut nibh quis felis auctor ornare. Cras ultricies, nibh at mollis faucibus, justo eros porttitor mi, quis auctor lectus arcu sit amet nunc.</span></p></div><div><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Nunc tincidunt, elit non cursus euismod, lacus augue ornare metus, egestas imperdiet nulla nisl quis mauris. Suspendisse a pharetra urna. Morbi dui lectus, pharetra nec elementum eget, vulputate ut nisi. Aliquam accumsan, nulla sed feugiat vehicula, lacus justo semper libero, quis porttitor turpis odio sit amet ligula. Duis dapibus fermentum orci, nec malesuada libero vehicula ut.</span></p><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Integer sodales, urna eget interdum eleifend, nulla nibh laoreet nisl, quis dignissim mauris dolor eget mi. Donec at mauris enim. Duis nisi tellus, adipiscing a convallis quis, tristique vitae risus. Nullam molestie gravida lobortis. Proin ut nibh quis felis auctor ornare. Cras ultricies, nibh at mollis faucibus, justo eros porttitor mi, quis auctor lectus arcu sit amet nunc.</span></p></div><div><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Nunc tincidunt, elit non cursus euismod, lacus augue ornare metus, egestas imperdiet nulla nisl quis mauris. Suspendisse a pharetra urna. Morbi dui lectus, pharetra nec elementum eget, vulputate ut nisi. Aliquam accumsan, nulla sed feugiat vehicula, lacus justo semper libero, quis porttitor turpis odio sit amet ligula. Duis dapibus fermentum orci, nec malesuada libero vehicula ut.</span></p><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Integer sodales, urna eget interdum eleifend, nulla nibh laoreet nisl, quis dignissim mauris dolor eget mi. Donec at mauris enim. Duis nisi tellus, adipiscing a convallis quis, tristique vitae risus. Nullam molestie gravida lobortis. Proin ut nibh quis felis auctor ornare. Cras ultricies, nibh at mollis faucibus, justo eros porttitor mi, quis auctor lectus arcu sit amet nunc.</span></p></div><div><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Nunc tincidunt, elit non cursus euismod, lacus augue ornare metus, egestas imperdiet nulla nisl quis mauris. Suspendisse a pharetra urna. Morbi dui lectus, pharetra nec elementum eget, vulputate ut nisi. Aliquam accumsan, nulla sed feugiat vehicula, lacus justo semper libero, quis porttitor turpis odio sit amet ligula. Duis dapibus fermentum orci, nec malesuada libero vehicula ut.</span></p><p><span style="color: rgb(116, 116, 116); font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Integer sodales, urna eget interdum eleifend, nulla nibh laoreet nisl, quis dignissim mauris dolor eget mi. Donec at mauris enim. Duis nisi tellus, adipiscing a convallis quis, tristique vitae risus. Nullam molestie gravida lobortis. Proin ut nibh quis felis auctor ornare. Cras ultricies, nibh at mollis faucibus, justo eros porttitor mi, quis auctor lectus arcu sit amet nunc.</span></p></div><p><br></p>
    <div class="footer">Footer :P</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I need a solution that works well on Safari and unfortunately or my hard luck, your snippet doesn't work on either Safari or iOS Safari. In case you have another workaround for the browsers, please let me know.

Comment: What error do you encounter in safari? Does the content not split up in multiple pages?

Comment: The content is unevenly scattered across pages irrespective of the CSS rules applied. Also, if we keep the height to exactly 29.7cm, blank pages appear in the middle due to ghost pixels. If you see the snippet in your answer in Safari, the difference in print view is startling.

Comment: Also, the footer that you have placed, i.e. page number is absolute element. The header and footer that I have are static elements appearing in continuation with the content. Not sure how to handle those and prevent overlap or clip.

Comment: Can you help me here

Comment: I have updated my answer, it formats the contents and divides them into div of size 720x1068 (fits a5 page). Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer

Comment: Changing the css height width of page-a5 it can be also fitted to a4 or other page size. Btw, does it work in safari? The print preview does not work well from inside snippet iframe.