# Want to repeat a div to fill its parent

Tags: html, css

I have a div that contains an image and some text.

I want to repeat this div so that it fills the whole of the parent.

ideally it would work the same way tiling an image for the backgorund would work but it is a div instead of a image getting tiled.

Comment: You need to provide your code and maybe some attempts you have made at solving this yourself

Comment: if it's only about text, length and size known, css could mimic it . Show your code and tries if you expect some help.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a way to do it just in plain html/css. 
You must use Javascript or another technology to clone the `div`.

Maybe take a look at [jQuery's .Clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) and make a `while` loop to check until [Parent overflows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143815/determine-if-an-html-elements-content-overflows)

Depending on your specific needs you could make an image out of the div and then just `background-repeat` it.