# How to check if a div is overflowing in react functional component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-forwardref

I am trying to find out if a div has overflown text and show `show more` link if it does. I found [this stackoverflow answer to check if a div is overflowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143815/determine-if-an-html-elements-content-overflows). According to this answer, I need to implement a function which can access styles of the element in question and do some checks to see if it is overflowing. How can I access the styles of an element. I tried 2 ways

**1. Using ref**

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App(props) {
  const [showMore, setShowMore] = React.useState(false);
  const onClick = () => {
    setShowMore(!showMore);
  };

  const checkOverflow = () => {
    const el = ref.current;
    const curOverflow = el.style.overflow;

    if ( !curOverflow || curOverflow === "visible" )
        el.style.overflow = "hidden";

    const isOverflowing = el.clientWidth < el.scrollWidth 
        || el.clientHeight < el.scrollHeight;

    el.style.overflow = curOverflow;

    return isOverflowing;
  };

  const ref = React.createRef();

  return (
    <>
      <div ref={ref} className={showMore ? "container-nowrap" : "container"}>
        {props.text}
      </div>
      {(checkOverflow()) && <span className="link" onClick={onClick}>
        {showMore ? "show less" : "show more"}
      </span>}
    </>
  )
}
```

**2. Using forward ref**

*Child component*

```
export const App = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [showMore, setShowMore] = React.useState(false);
  const onClick = () => {
    setShowMore(!showMore);
  };

  const checkOverflow = () => {
    const el = ref.current;
    const curOverflow = el.style.overflow;

    if (!curOverflow || curOverflow === "visible") el.style.overflow = "hidden";

    const isOverflowing =
      el.clientWidth < el.scrollWidth || el.clientHeight < el.scrollHeight;

    el.style.overflow = curOverflow;

    return isOverflowing;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div ref={ref} className={showMore ? "container-nowrap" : "container"}>
        {props.text}
      </div>
      {checkOverflow() && (
        <span className="link" onClick={onClick}>
          {showMore ? "show less" : "show more"}
        </span>
      )}
    </>
  );
});
```

*Parent component*

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { App } from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const ref = React.createRef();
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App
      ref={ref}
      text="Start editing to see some magic happen! Click show more to expand and show less to collapse the text"
    />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

But I got the following error in both approaches - `Cannot read property 'style' of null`.
What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: The first time you render your component, the `ref` will not be set yet. Only after that first render will `ref.current` have a value.

Comment: I don't have a good answer for this because I'm not entirely sure what the best practice is, but one thing I've done in my app for a similar situation is initially set `showMore` to `null` and have `useLayoutEffect` with an empty dependency list `[]` where I then do `setShowMore(false)` to trigger the re-render where `ref.current` will be available.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Jamie Dixon suggested in the comment, I used `useLayoutEffect` hook to set `showLink` true. Here is the code

**Component**

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App(props) {
  const ref = React.createRef();
  const [showMore, setShowMore] = React.useState(false);
  const [showLink, setShowLink] = React.useState(false);

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current.clientWidth < ref.current.scrollWidth) {
      setShowLink(true);
    }
  }, [ref]);

  const onClickMore = () => {
    setShowMore(!showMore);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={ref} className={showMore ? "" : "container"}>
        {props.text}
      </div>
      {showLink && (
        <span className="link more" onClick={onClickMore}>
          {showMore ? "show less" : "show more"}
        </span>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 200px;
}

.link {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #0d6aa8;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

We could create a custom hooks to know if we have overflow.

```js
import * as React from 'react';

const useIsOverflow = (ref, isVerticalOverflow, callback) => {
  const [isOverflow, setIsOverflow] = React.useState(undefined);

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const { current } = ref;
    const { clientWidth, scrollWidth, clientHeight, scrollHeight } = current;

    const trigger = () => {
      const hasOverflow = isVerticalOverflow ? scrollHeight > clientHeight : scrollWidth > clientWidth;

      setIsOverflow(hasOverflow);

      if (callback) callback(hasOverflow);
    };

    if (current) {
      trigger();
    }
  }, [callback, ref, isVerticalOverflow]);

  return isOverflow;
};

export default useIsOverflow;
```

and just check in your component

```js
import * as React from 'react';

import { useIsOverflow } from './useIsOverflow';

const App = () => {
  const ref = React.useRef();
  const isOverflow = useIsOverflow(ref);

  console.log(isOverflow);
  // true

  return (
    <div style={{ overflow: 'auto', height: '100px' }} ref={ref}>
      <div style={{ height: '200px' }}>Hello React</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Thanks to Robin Wieruch for his awesome articles
https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-custom-hook-check-if-overflow/

Answer (score 2):

Solution using TS and Hooks

Create your custom hook:

```
import React from 'react'

interface OverflowY {
  ref: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>
  isOverflowY: boolean
}

export const useOverflowY = (
  callback?: (hasOverflow: boolean) => void
): OverflowY => {
  const [isOverflowY, setIsOverflowY] = React.useState(false)
  const ref = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const { current } = ref

    if (current && hasOverflowY !== isOverflowY) {
      const hasOverflowY = current.scrollHeight > window.innerHeight
      // RHS of assignment could be current.scrollHeight > current.clientWidth
      setIsOverflowY(hasOverflowY)
      callback?.(hasOverflowY)
    }
  }, [callback, ref])

  return { ref, isOverflowY }
}
```

use your hook:

```
const { ref, isOverflowY } = useOverflowY()
//...
<Box ref={ref}>
...code
```

Import your files as need be and update code to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for his solution. The `useLayoutEffect` gives me an error in the terminal even though the UI works correctly. The error led me to this link https://gist.github.com/gaearon/e7d97cdf38a2907924ea12e4ebdf3c85 and I used the first option to eliminate the error, i.e., using a `useEffect` in place of `useLayoutEffect` and the terminal error goes away and the UI still works correctly.

Comment: It's not best practice to place `setIsOverflowY(hasOverflowY)
callback?.(hasOverflowY)
`
in every update. Better to make something like `if (hasOverflowY !== isOverflowY) {
    setIsOverflowY(hasOverflowY)
    callback?.(hasOverflowY)
}`

Comment: That’s a great idea!