# Read more button only if text is breaking

Tags: html, jquery, css

I would like to create a "read more" button that only will show if the text inside a wrapper is breaking.

This is my code so far:

**HTML**

```
<div class="comment-wrapper">
    <div class="text">
        Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum. ipsum. Lorem ipsum
        Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum
        Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum.
    </div>
    <div class="read-more">Read more</div>
    <div class="read-less">Read less</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.read-more{
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
.read-less{
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    text-align: left;
}

.comment-wrapper.open .read-more {
    display: none;
}
.comment-wrapper.open .read-less {
    display: block;
}

.comment-wrapper .text {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
.comment-wrapper.open .text {
    display: block;
}
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(".read-more").on("click",function(){
    jQuery($(this)).parent('div').addClass('open');
});

jQuery(".read-less").on("click",function(){
    jQuery($(this)).parent('div').removeClass('open');
});
```

How can I achieve this within this code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143815/determine-if-an-html-elements-content-overflows

Answer (score 1):

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  $('.comment-wrapper').each(function() {
    var scrollHeight = this.getElementsByClassName('text')[0].scrollHeight;
    var clientHeight = this.getElementsByClassName('text')[0].clientHeight;
    var thisElem = this;
    if ( scrollHeight > clientHeight ) {
      $(this).children('.read-more').show();
    } else {
      $(thisElem).find('.read-more, .read-less').hide();
    }
    $(this).children(".read-more").on("click", function() {
      console.log('done');
      $(thisElem).find('.read-more, .read-less').toggle();
    });

    $(this).children(".read-less").on("click", function() {
      $(thisElem).find('.read-more, .read-less').toggle();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! this is a working solution for me!!
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
     var scrollHeight = document.getElementsByClassName('text')[0].scrollHeight;
     var clientHeight = document.getElementsByClassName('text')[0].clientHeight;

     if( scrollHeight > clientHeight ) {
        $('.read-more').show();
     } else {
        $('.read-more, .read-less').hide();
     }
     $(".read-more").on("click",function(){
        $('.read-more, .read-less').toggle();
    });

    $(".read-less").on("click",function(){
        $('.read-more, .read-less').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer!! I implemented it in the code, but unfortunately now I can't see any buttons?

Comment: You should set .read-less display: none; When window loaded and text is small buttons hidden, when text big buttons show

Comment: If text big and buttons show, after click buttons read-less and read-more will change

Comment: your code with addClass and removeClass is not required

Comment: Sorry, You should set .read-more display: none; It will show if text will be big

Comment: ah, I understand thank you very much! Last question in order to solve this issue: is there something to select each 'text' classes because I've multiple of them. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: You can use id for each class, also use $('.class').eq(1) with number in list in dom or use "each" for all .text divs

Comment: This answer would be better with some explanation or inline documentation.

Comment: I add in css:
.text {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 overflow: auto;
}
and .read-more{
    display: none;
}

Comment: js i can`t add to comment, so i added as answer