# Detecting text overflow using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a component where I am displaying a colon (:) separated list of text. I only need to display that part of the text up to the colon from the start which will be completely visible without over flowing. The rest needs to be truncated. I am using the following code to check for overflow.

```js
function checkOverflow(el) {
  var curOverflow = window.getComputedStyle(el).overflow
  if (!curOverflow || curOverflow === 'visible') {
    el.style.overflow = 'hidden'
  }
  var isOverflowing = el.clientWidth < el.scrollWidth
  el.style.overflow = curOverflow
  return isOverflowing
}

const tableComponent = () => {
  const view = document.getElementById('outer-view')
  console.log(checkOverflow(view))
  console.log(view.scrollWidth, view.clientWidth)
}

document.addEventListener('readystatechange', () => {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    tableComponent()
  }
})
```

```css
#outer-view {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightpink;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer-view">{status}</div>
```

- Here **status** is the variable containing the string of colon separated texts.
  **(eg. XQV:HGAHGCDHD:KJDGKDGKDHGD.....)**.
- Also for more clarity lets assume that this div is inside another div whose **max-width** is set to **300px**.
- The text will always be single line. It will never be multiline.
- It is not clamped with elipsis. I am not adding elipsis at the end if it overflows. I have a different logic to run and to change the ui if overflow occurs.
- I will need to detect overflow change on browser resize as well (which should not be a problem as I can call this function again on **resize** event.)

This code is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143815/determine-if-an-html-elements-content-overflows) article but for every case whether the text overflows or not the checkOverflow() always returns false. I also tried checking the scrollWidth and the clientWidth but in every case their value is same. I also tried enclosing the string within a p tag and then try to get the width difference of the div and p tag but they are also the same in every case, irrespective of the fact whether the text overflows or not.

I have tried all the solutions mentioned but none of them seem to work.
Any help in this matter will be greatly appreciated.

*I know that there are multiple answers for my issue, but I wrote this article because none of the solutions seem to work in my case.*

Thanks to **@vsync** for pointing out the missing details.

Comment: How exactly do you define "overflowing" for this element? Because you've set its dimensions to `width: 100%; height: 100%;`. More than a screens worth of content? Then you'd need to check the height too, not just the width.

Comment: Actually this component is inside another div that has a fixed width of around 250px.

Comment: Why are you asking us to *assume* things which you can easily include in your example code...?

Comment: Can the text be multiline or only one-line? is it clamped with ellipsis? do you need to detect overflow on-the-fly, for example on resizing the browser or the element itself? you need to be more specific